# How to ask a genlist to be display-only

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

As the question states: I need a genlist which is display-only, i.e. items are not selectable.

It's not an EFL thing, as EFL supports this by default.

I want to get rid of this framing around my items:

[image]

I have tried:

- ELM_OBJECT_SELECT_MODE_NONE
- ELM_OBJECT_SELECT_MODE_DISPLAY_ONLY
- elm_genlist_highlight_mode_set

Nothing worked, do we know a solution for removing this frame?

Answer (score 0):

[elm_genlist_select_mode_set](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/mobile/5.5/group__Elm__Genlist__Group.html#gaf037c92717b93ea122ae26c757a23c65) is for all item to be selected or not.
[_elm_genlist_item_select_mode_set](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/mobile/5.5/group__Elm__Genlist__Item__Group.html#gac9f8157c9634d50edbf230b2df88b94a) is for single item to be selected or not.

also you can [disable](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/5.5/group__Elm__General.html#ga1d4c8d3c83ed9408eaa35d605adbd7d2) item to be not selected.

Comment: I can disable, but that "highlight" frame is always keep staying there

Comment: you meant the white background? I was misunderstanding your question.. it is not related with select or highlight.
it is only controlled by edc styles. turn focus_bg to off in data.item.

Comment: I have no control over `data.item` as I'm using `1text` style (and I'm still not able to checkout the code due to email issues), so I don't have the source of `1text`.